# setting a default command for bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

Suppose I create my own script and I want that script to be the default command to be executed if command is not found, how do I go about configuring bash to make this happen

Eg. the command is called defCMD

Suppose I type some random string into the command line:

```
$ viosjaldfksajflsfa
```

Normally it would output 'viosjaldfksajflsfa not found'

However, instead of that happening I want 'viosjaldfksajflsfa' to be fed as parameter into the defCMD script I wrote and therefore have bash execute defCMD instead.

is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bash (Fedora) has the following

```
$ type command_not_found_handle 
command_not_found_handle is a function
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    runcnf=1;
    retval=127;
    [ ! -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ] && runcnf=0;
    [ ! -x /usr/libexec/packagekitd ] && runcnf=0;
    if [ $runcnf -eq 1 ]; then
        /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found $@;
        retval=$?;
    else
        echo "bash: $1: command not found";
    fi;
    return $retval
}
```

You can start from here and add it to your `.bashrc` file. Change the `else` branch.

Comment: `command_not_found_handle` was introduced in `bash` 4.0, but I think most Linux distributions have upgraded to something in the 4.x series by now.